# Monitor progress of source on save in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to see what line Rstudio is at after sourcing a file?

Suppose I have a file with 10 lines and each line takes a few minutes or more to execute. I use the *source on save*  option and would like to know at some point how much progress has been made, for example by knowing which line is currently being executed. Is there a way in Rstudio to see this (without adding extra code*)?

*A simple, but perhaps messy way, to do this is to print the line number after each of the existing lines. In this case, I am inquiring if there exists another way to do which is already built in Rstudio.

Comment: If you're looking for progress when sourcing, you're looking for a progress bar in the console, as you'll find in IDEs for other languages. I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure RStudio doesn't have that option unless it's new. 

There are packages and there's a [nice blog post](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/) by [Mark Heckman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536198/mark-heckmann) on creating a progress bar, but that will involve coding. If I'm right about there not being any option in RStudio, any solution to this will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly *without extra code* and not *on save* but it's partial solution. Create a R-Notebook document in RStudio. It's a R Markdown document. When you add a chunk of R code:

````
```{r}
plot(cars)
Sys.sleep(10)
library(dplyr)
```
````

you have an option to run it (green arrow on the right). The green bar on the right will point exactly at which line the chunk is at this very moment:

[image]

At least that solves you an issue of adding logger/messages to your code.